# Is there any way to achieve this in a MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, set, declare

What I am trying to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzsCT.png

SELECT message, "Need to add user here"
FROM database WHERE source="Device Thresholds"

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Answer (score 0):

You could create another table with possible responses, based on your question.  Joining your table with "message" in one table and joining it with another table with "possible responses" may work.

Comment: I only have read only access unfortunataly so this is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be ok but cant get the syntax correct

SELECT message, SUBSTRING(message,7,6)
FROM database WHERE source="Device Thresholds"

Where the number 6 is for number of characters I would like to find part of the srting as number of charachters which in my case would be "' "

SELECT message, SUBSTRING(message,7,find("' ",message))
FROM database WHERE source="Device Thresholds"

But this brings back an error